# com.sun.proxy.$ProxyXX cannot be cast to org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-commons-dbcp

Java 1.7, Commons-dbcp1.2.2 jar, JDBC

how to type cast a java.sql.Connection to org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection ?

```
Connection conn = null;
DataSource objDS = null;
objDS = (DataSource)new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/new_con");
conn = objDS.getConnection();
// Here i am getting connection fine

tempconn = ((DelegatingConnection)conn).getInnermostDelegate(); // Here it is throwing exception com.sun.proxy.$ProxyXX cannot be cast to org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection

oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor desc = new oracle.sql.ArrayDescriptor("string", tempconn);
oracle.sql.ARRAY reportDataArray = new ARRAY(desc, tempconn,ipList.toArray());
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using DBCP, and not another connection pool? Have you tried using `conn.unwrap(DelegatingConnection.class)` instead?

Comment: Yes i am sure @MarkRotteveel i tried with 'tempconn = conn.unwrap(DelegatingConnection.class)' Exception Occurred : Not a wrapper of org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Any help on this ?

Comment: Sorry, no, I still think you are not using DBCP (or a different DBCP).